# Python Pandas. Date object split by separate columns.

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have dates in Python (pandas) written as "1/31/2010". To apply linear regression I want to have 3 separate variables: number of day, number of month, number of year.

What will be the way to split a column with date in pandas into 3 columns?
Another question is to have the same but group days into 3 groups: 1-10, 11-20, 21-31.

Comment: Can you please separate the second question as an independent one? It is not really related to the first one and it can make it difficult for other users to find an easy Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#Create 3 additional columns
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
```

Ideally, you can do this without having to create 3 additional columns, you can just pass the `Series` to your function.

```
In [2]: pd.to_datetime('01/31/2010').day
Out[2]: 31

In [3]: pd.to_datetime('01/31/2010').month
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: pd.to_datetime('01/31/2010').year
Out[4]: 2010
```

Comment: You might consider specifying your date format explicitly using `format='%m/%d/%Y'` in the call to `to_datetime`

Comment: @iDrwish, would you mind splitting OP's question in 2 (can even do your own Q&A)? Reason is people won't be able to find an easy Q&A with multiple questions combined. And, of course, you probably deserve an upvote for each solution..

Comment: @jpp thanks for pointing this out, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @iDrwish, Sure, I really don't want SO to *lose* your good answer to the second bit. So if OP doesn't make a new question, please feel free to do it yourself!

Comment: Actually, the second Q&A is adapted from an answer you @jpp gave earlier today, so no value is lost.

Answer (score 0):

**This answers only your first question**

One solution is to extract attributes of `pd.Timestamp` objects using `operator.attrgetter`.

The benefit of this method is you can easily expand / change the attributes you require. In addition, the logic is not specific to object type.

```
from operator import attrgetter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['1/21/2010', '5/5/2015', '4/30/2018']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

attr_list = ['day', 'month', 'year']
attrs = attrgetter(*attr_list)
df[attr_list] = df['date'].apply(attrs).apply(pd.Series)

print(df)

        date  day  month  year
0 2010-01-21   21      1  2010
1 2015-05-05    5      5  2015
2 2018-04-30   30      4  2018
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'yyyymmdd': ['20150204', '20160305']})
for col, field in [("year", "%Y"), ("month", "%m"), ("day", "%d")]:
    df[col] = df["yyyymmdd"].apply(
        lambda cell: datetime.strptime(cell, "%Y%m%d").strftime(field))
    
print(df)

   yyyymmdd  year month day
0  20150204  2015    02  04
1  20160305  2016    03  05
```